# How to make background photo fit a div and responsive in Css?

Tags: image, responsive

I have a really cool photo as my website portfolio but i cant get it responsive and fit the div. It fills the entire div but the entire photo isnt fittinf properly. I am using bootstrap.

This is my css

```
                    .bg1 {
                       background-image: url (../img/brain.jpg);
                       background-size: 100%;
                       height: 600px;
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.bg1{
      background-image: url (../img/brain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Demo [link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

More info here: [Perfect Full Page background](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try load your image with a `<img>` tag, and add `img-responsive` class which is supported by Bootstrap. See more in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp